# Check if user is authenticated with django TokenAuthentication

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to develop a REST API with DRF that uses `TokenAuthentication`. This will be used in an android app.

I was able to authenticate a user and retrieve it's token. The problem I'm having now is with the following view:

```
@csrf_exempt
def foo(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            ...
            do stuff
            ...
            return HttpResponse(data, "application/json")
        else:
            return HttpResponse(status=401)
```

Basically the user should be authenticated in order to receive the data, otherwise, he will receive a 401 response.

I'm making a GET request to the proper URL with the following parameters in the Header:

```
content-type : application/json
authorization : Token <user token>
```

Which is basically what I'm doing for other **Viewsets** (this is not a Viewset) I have - and it works.

In this case, it's always sending the HTTP response with 401 code (user isn't authenticated).

I can't figure out if the problem is with the Header values I'm passing or if this is not the proper way to check if the user is authenticated.

**Edit:** if I do: "print request.user" i get AnonymousUser

Thanks!

**Solved**

As suggested by "ABDUL NIYAS P M" I used the APIView

Basically, I just added the **@api_view(['GET'])** decorator to the View.

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, ))
def foo(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        ...
```

Comment: Abdu, I was missing the api_view decorator as you said before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do this is by checking if the user session is existing or not.

When DRF creates a token, it also creates the session cookie.

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"is_authenticated": True if request.session.get('_auth_user_id', 0) else False}),
                            content_type='application/json')
```